# android_getCpuFeatures crashes on Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an NDK project that calls android_getCpuFeatures early on. This works fine on all phones I tested, but on a Honeycomb tablet, it simply crashes (the Logcat doesn't have much information, other than that there was a hard crash).

This is with the r5b NDK, using the new, preferred way of getting the CPU features function in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not the answer, but you can investigate it with the source code ([cpu-features.c](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/ndk.git;a=blob;f=sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c;h=b027ea4b5cdbc384f0ac67ecab83fc6009271028;hb=HEAD), [cpu-features.h](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/ndk.git;a=blob;f=sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.h;h=837c7c2278788d69cd2809120938df43f19e444d;hb=HEAD)).

android_getCpuFeatures just checks the strings that is taken from /proc/cpuinfo, it seems ok on every Android kernel.

Comment: Mystery solved, thanks to your advice: According to /proc/cpuinfo, the Tegra 2 based tablet doesn't have NEON support! I had compiled my app for NEON. I didn't actually use any NEON types or intrinsics, but I guess the compiler optimized some code to use NEON.

Comment: Tegra 2 also doesn't have VFPv3-D32 registers. Thus some floating-point instructions of armv7-a-neon, such as division instruction, doesn't work. armv7-a is the best arch type for Tegra 2.